# Cross reference table in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

When generating the cross-reference table in crystal and it is very large, it does not extend to a second page, it is possible to cut it and have it appear on the same page with a page break or a similar process

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECCr1.png)

- make the text smaller
- adapt it in different types of sheets
- review crosstab settings

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: break the ***crosstab*** by placing it in a Group Header or Footer.
Create a formula that separates all the records into 2 groups, and Group the report on that formula.

Option 2: pivot the CrossTab to use rows instead of columns.

Option 3: Turn off 'Show Cell Margins'. This would result in a much tighter layout:
[image: CrossTab option to show/hide cell margins]